# Не понимаю в чем ошибка. django ajax pagination

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

Проблема в том что переключаясь по страницам ничего не выводится. Изначально всё есть, начинаю кликать по страницам - всё пропадает.

Code views.py

```
class ReviewsView(ListView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'reviews.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['reviews'] = Review.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(context['reviews'], 1)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            context['reviews'] = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            context['reviews'] = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            context['reviews'] = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return context
```

Code reviews.html

```
        <div id="reviews" class="row md-3">
            {% for review in reviews %}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="reviews-card reviews__link">
                        <div class="reviews-card__box">
                            <div class="reviews-card__author">
                                <div class="reviews-card__preview">
                                    <picture>
                                        <img class="reviews-card__img" src="{{ review.photo.url }}"
                                             alt="{{ review.name }} {{ review.surname }}"></picture>
                                </div>
                                <div class="reviews-card__name">{{ review.name }}<br>{{ review.surname }}</div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="reviews-card__text">{{ review.content }}</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        {% if not reviews.paginator.page_range|length == 1 %}
            <div class="pagination__wrapper">
                <div id="pagination" class="pagination">
                    {% for page in reviews.paginator.page_range %}
                        {% if reviews.number == page %}
                            <span class="active">{{ page }}</span>
                        {% elif page > reviews.number|add:-2 and page < reviews.number|add:2 %}
                            <a class="page" href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if reviews.has_next %}
                        <a class="page" href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ reviews.next_page_number }}">{{ page }}
                            >>
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Code js

```
{% block js %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxPagination() {
            $('#pagination a.page').each((index, el) => {
                $(el).click((e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let page_url = $(el).attr('href')
                    console.log(page_url)

                    $.ajax({
                        url: page_url,
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: (data) => {
                            $('#reviews').empty()
                            $('#reviews').append($(data).filter('#reviews').html())

                            $('#pagination').empty()
                            $('#pagination').append($(data).find('#pagination').html())
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            ajaxPagination();
        })

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            ajaxPagination();
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите здесь на русский.

Comment: А я думал не на ru пишу, крч проблема в том что переключаясь по страницам ничего не выводится. Изначально всё есть, начинаю кликать по страницам - всё пропадает

Comment: не мне перевести надо было, а в вопросе:-)))